# Creating a NLP driven chatbot

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, chat-bots, resource-request

I would like to create a chat bot for an e-commerce website that sells a wide range of general merchandize items, from t-shirts, jumpers to calculators. Its primary objective is to develop a Q&A option for visitors/potential customers, to improve engagement on the website. As such, the chat bot is required to be fairly conversational.

I am experienced in classification et al, but know only the very basics on NLP. Can you provide suggestions on where to begin, e.g., recommended readings/ sources?

Also note, there is currently has no chat bot system in place, and hence no historical conversation data of any form.

Comment: Hello. You need to be more specific. Have you done some research before asking this question? Tell us what you have found so far and why it doesn't meet your needs. Please, take the time to read: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [deeplearning.ai Natural Language Processing Specialization](https://www.deeplearning.ai/program/natural-language-processing-specialization/), is a great place to start. It'll brush up some basic concepts of NLP and then get into SOTA methods  such as Transformers. There's even a project in one of the courses about building a chatbot using transformers, it also has a ton of papers and other sources mentioned.
2. [Rasa](https://rasa.com/) is a great software tool/package to get started with chatbots too. It's a great engaging community so your queries should be quickly answered.